# Server Timing out when attempting install of libcurl4-openssl-dev

Tags: networking, package-management

Fair warning, I am still new to all this and using OpenMediaVault to serve my media.  So dumb it down if you can, The end goal of this is to install "Jackett"

When I attempt:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

It looks like it's working, but then Winscp gives me a time out error.

[image]